# linkers, absolute references, and a processes address space

Tags: memory-management, linker

I'm quite confused reading up on relocating absolute references, shared libraries and position-independent code. I hypothesize that I don't know enough yet about an individual processess address space.

In my book, the author talks about a link resolving absolute symbol references by inserting the **run-time** address of the global variable/function. How does the linker know this? I could compile, link, create my executable, and run it N different times.. I'm guessing that it won't be loaded into the same place in memory each time, so how could the linker possibly know the absolute runtime address of a variable/function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker deals in virtual addresses. The absolute address, is the absolute virtual address.

Each process instance will have the exact same virtual address space.

Comment: OK, this is what I was thinking. But this raises the question: why is not all code position-independent? If any program has the same virtual address space every time it is loaded, why does it matter where the program is physically loaded? I.e, shouldn't all programs be position-independent?

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. But it is possible that you are mixing up the pre-link notions of relocatable code, and position independent code etc., with the post-link notion of the address space for the executable. The code generated for individual object files can be relocatable or position independent etc. The former can be placed anywhere in the address space by the linker using the relocation process. The latter can be placed anywhere in the address space, no action required. Once these objects have been placed (linked together), the executable has a fixed virtual address space.

Comment: OK. So when I use the `-fPIC` flag for position-independent code for a shared library, what happens? The shared library is present only once in physical memory, but can be mapped into arbitrary locations in the virtual address space of multiple processes?

Comment: The -fPIC option applies to the object file(s) that you compile. A library is simply an archive of one or more objects. No linking has happened as yet. For shared libraries, the dynamic linker completes the link to the executable at run time. It locates the objects from the library in the address space of the executable somewhere, and performs the link (much like the static linker). The sharing part happens by virtue of the fact that only one instance of the shared library lives in physical memory, which is mapped into the address space of multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  Typically, a linker does not know about the absolute address and generates what is known as a relocatable address.  In a very simple model of things, the relocatable address is bound to an absolute address at run-time.

Comment: What modifies the relocatable addresses? The loader? I don't understand

Comment: I'll encourage you to refer to a book on Operating Systems and look up the virtual memory chapter.  Typically, you will need hardware support for the final address binding.